# How to fix JS not adapting to new HTML input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow my users to choose a search engine for the homepage I'm making. The problem is if they choose one and want to go back to the other - the result is the same

I've tried if then statements, but it stays the same if the user chooses something different.

```js
function search() {
  var se = document.getElementById("se").value;
  var query = document.getElementById("search").value;
  
  if (se.value = "ddg") {
    var searchb4plus = "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + query
  }
  if (se.value = "google") {
    var searchb4plus = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query
  }
  
  var search = searchb4plus.split(' ').join('+');
  window.open(search, "_self");
}
```

```html
<input id=search placeholder=" Search now!" maxlength=100>

<button onclick=search()></button>

<p style="color:black;">Search Engine:</p>

<select id=se>
  <option value=ddg>DuckDuckGo</option>
  <option value=google>Google</option>
</select>

<br>

<p style="color:black;">These settings don't save.</p>

<br>

<button onclick=hsettings() style="display:none;" id=sbutton>Hide Settings</button>
```

The expected result is if they at first choose Google and then want to use DuckDuckGo, they just search DuckDuckGo.
Instead, it still uses Google even after they select DDG.

Comment: Show us the HTML as well

Comment: can you please provide your HTML and the part which calls the `search()` method

Comment: yeah hold on sorry my bad

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned in the answer below, the issue is in your if statements you're assigning values, rather than comparing. You need to use === in your if statements.

Comment: Please review your HTML syntax. Make sure you use quotes to surround the attribute values. Also, `<br>` should not be used in layout adjustments; use CSS instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem 1**

Look at the line:

```
var se = document.getElementById('se').value
```

You are already taking its value by the `.value` property.

And then, in your `if` statements, you have:

```
if (se.value = 'ddg')
```

You are using the `.value` again. However, this time, it is not the value of `input#se` but the "value" property of the string value of `input#se`. There is no `.value` property in `String`, so it's undefined.

What you should do is to take the `.value` property only from the actual element.

```
function search() {
    var se = document.getElementById("se");
    var query = document.getElementById("search").value;
    if (se.value = "ddg") {var searchb4plus = "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + query}
    if (se.value = "google") {var searchb4plus = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query}
    var search = searchb4plus.split(' ').join('+');
    window.open(search, "_self");
}
```

OR

```
function search() {
    var se = document.getElementById("se").value;
    var query = document.getElementById("search").value;
    if (se = "ddg") {var searchb4plus = "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + query}
    if (se = "google") {var searchb4plus = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query}
    var search = searchb4plus.split(' ').join('+');
    window.open(search, "_self");
}
```

**Problem 2**

In your `if` statements, you wrote:

```
if (se.value = 'ddg')
```

Notice the single `=` sign. [Single "=" sign is for value assignment, not for comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). So the last `if` will always return `true`, so your user will always search using Google and never DDG.

You should write it like:

```
if (se.value === 'ddg')
```

**Working Sample**

```js
function search() {
  var se = document.getElementById("se");
  var query = document.getElementById("search").value;
  
  if (se.value === "ddg") {
    var searchb4plus = "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + query
  }
  if (se.value === "google") {
    var searchb4plus = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query
  }
  
  var search = searchb4plus.split(' ').join('+');
  /* Comment this out because can't open tab using SO's code snippet
  window.open(search, "_self");
  */
  console.log(search)
}
```

```html
<input id=search placeholder=" Search now!" maxlength=100>

<button onclick=search()></button>

<p style="color:black;">Search Engine:</p>

<select id=se>
  <option value=ddg>DuckDuckGo</option>
  <option value=google>Google</option>
</select>

<br>

<p style="color:black;">These settings don't save.</p>

<br>

<button onclick=hsettings() style="display:none;" id=sbutton>Hide Settings</button>
```

Comment: Just curious, any reason not to just check `if (se === 'ddg')`? Is it preferable/better practice to keep the variable the "full" element?

Comment: Nope. It's totally up to the developer. In the answer I offered two options. In the working code I only included one because including both options is overkill for a simple explanation. The best practice is to choose the option that is most easily understandable in each particular context.